# ETA Application "Have you previously applied to enter or remain in Canada"?

Tags: canada, german-citizens, eta

I am from Germany and I would like to visit Canada for 3 weeks in August. Therefore I have to apply for an ETA.

One question asks "Have you previously applied to enter or remain in Canada?". I studied in Canada from September 2013 until December 2013 (4 months) but I did not apply for a study permit because it was not necessary as a student from Germany.

Do I have to answer this question with yes or no?

Comment: You should find your answer in the linked duplicate.  If you still have questions after reading that, please respond to this comment (and/or edit your question to clarify).

Answer (score 0):

If you answered Yes to this question, you'll need a Unique Client Identification, permit or visa number.

If you don't have such a number, answer 'No.'